# Scroll RecyclerVIew to specific position when Fragment starts

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am creating an android application. I want to create functionality like in Instagram, so that when you click on a notification, you will be immediately taken to the desired comment. And I don’t know how to do it. For comments, I am using RecyclerView. I have already searched the Internet for information and tried to use scrollToPosition (), smoothScrollToPosition (), but there is no effect. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
private void loadUserPosts()
    {
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

        new SetFirebaseRecyclerAdapter().execute();
    }
```

Nested class:

```
class SetFirebaseRecyclerAdapter extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TestPosts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TestPosts>()
                    .setQuery(mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid), TestPosts.class)
                    .build();

            mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
            mLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
            mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            adapter = new TestPostsAdapter(options, mContext);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
                            adapter.startListening();
                            mRecyclerView.invalidate();

                            mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                    }
            );



        }
    }
```

Comment: This is an asynchronous operation you have here. The Firebase thing will take time to fetch your items, sort them, etc. Yet you create your adapter, you set it in the RV and you ask it to scroll all in the same frame... Read on Asynchronous programming for Android using a Coroutines (or any other mechanism that suits you, there are plenty of resources online). In short, you need to create your adapter and set it, ask for the data, wait for it, then set the data, then scroll the adapter.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini would he want to scroll the adapter or the LayoutManager?

Comment: @eimmer LayoutManager

Comment: @lin that is what I thought

Comment: Well yes, you scroll the RecyclerView, and the Adapter supplies the data and converts it to Views, and the Layout Manager lays out the views according to its rules; but you ask the RecyclerView to scroll to a position, everything else (adapter, layout manager) are implementation details and delegates of a RecyclerView, not the other way around.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I've added some new code with AsyncTask and it still doesn't work, maye you can help